# How to know UIBarButtonItem selector's name

Tags: ios, selector, uibarbuttonitem

I'm developing an SplitView based app for iOS

where I added a button on my master viewcontroller for hidding this view, I did it like this

**MasterViewController.m**

```
- (IBAction)hideMasterViewController:(id)sender {
    
    
    if (!app) { app = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; }
    if (!currentSplitViewController) {
        currentSplitViewController  = (UISplitViewController *) app.window.rootViewController;
    }
    
    navController        = [currentSplitViewController.viewControllers lastObject];
    
    UIBarButtonItem *button = [[[[navController childViewControllers] objectAtIndex:0] navigationItem ] leftBarButtonItem];
    
    [button.target performSelector:button.action];
    
}
```

as you can see I added the functionallyty of my Detail View Controller's leftBarButtonItem on my own button and then I ordered to perform it's own selector here

```
[button.target performSelector:button.action];
```

but now I get this warning :

> PerformSelector may cause a leak because its selector is unknown

I did that way since Detail Controller has it prebuilt and I don't know it's selector's name, how to know that???

---

**EDIT:** these are my two screens:

**DetailViewController** (original pre-built button)
[image]

**MasterViewController** (where I developed my button clone from pre-built button in detail view)
[image]

---

**EDIT:** thanks to Jesus gonna put my answer:

```
- (IBAction)hideMasterViewController:(id)sender {
    
    
    if (!app) { app = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; }
    if (!currentSplitViewController) {
        currentSplitViewController  = (UISplitViewController *) app.window.rootViewController;
    }
    
    navController        = [currentSplitViewController.viewControllers lastObject];
    
    UIBarButtonItem *button = [[[[navController childViewControllers] objectAtIndex:0] navigationItem ] leftBarButtonItem];
    
    
    [button.target performSelector:@selector(toggleMasterVisible:)];
}

-(IBAction)toggleMasterVisible:(id)sender{
    
}
```

1. I could get selector's name with `NSStringFromSelector(button.action)`
2. after changing performSelector with selector's name I had another warning because toggleMasterVisible: was not declared (locally), so I turned it off by adding that IBAction  but I did never set to my button

Comment: It looks like you're hiding the master view controller from code in the master view controller. If that's so, why do you need the selector from a button in the detail controller? Why not just have master view controller hide itself?

Comment: I'm hiding master view controller from master view controller itself, I drawed a button which I set hidding action of detail's view controller because customer wanted a button on menú for hidding it, I'll upload a screenshot –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
NSStringFromSelector(button.action)
```